How can I convert a string into a list of characters in Python?
I want to convert a string into a list containing the individual characters of that string in Python. How can I do that in a simple way?
my_string = "hello"

Expected result: ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
my_string = "hello"


I tried splitting the string using the split() method, but it didn't work for characters.
split_string = my_string.split()  # This splits by spaces, not by characters.
print(split_string)


You can try split_string = list(my_string). Marking this as duplicate.
